# Как получить старые данные(до $model->attributes=$_GET) в модели ActiveRecord Yii?

Tags: php, yii, activerecord

Всем привет. в afterSave модели мне нужно знать, были ли изменены некоторые поля. возможно ли получить старые данные модели стандартным способом yii, или придется писать свой костыль?

Comment: Создайте заново модель по тому же PK. Только не сохраняйте ее, а то будет бесконечная рекурсия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{  
  public $oldRecord;

  public function afterFind()
  {
      $this->oldRecord=clone $this;
      return parent::afterFind();     
  }
```

Теперь можно получить доступ:

```
$this->oldRecord->someField;
```

Другой вариант:

```
class MyModel extends CActiveRecord
{
  private $_oldAttributes = array();
  public function setOldAttributes($value)
  {
    $this->_oldAttributes = $value;
  }
  public function getOldAttributes()
  {
    return $this->_oldAttributes;
  }

  public function init()
  {
    $this->attachEventHandler("onAfterFind", function ($event)
    {
      $event->sender->OldAttributes = $event->sender->Attributes;
    }
  }
}
```

Обращаться теперь так:

```
// Внутри моедели
$OldColumnInfo = $this->OldAttributes['ColumnName'];

// Через инстанс
$OldColumnInfo = $MyModelInstance->OldAttributes['ColumnName'];
```